# Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i dont know ahy i got this error

**Main**

```
IBanqueMetier metier;
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context
        = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[]{"applicationContext.xml"});
    metier = (IBanqueMetier) context.getBean("metier");
    metier.addClient(new Client("Client1","Adress1"));
```

**BanqueDaoImpl**

```
public class BanqueDaoImpl implements IBanqueDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Client addClient(Client c) {
        // j'enregistre le client c et je le retourne
        em.persist(c);
        return c;
    }
....
```

and this the 1rst error :

```
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1be847c: startup date [Fri Feb 05 14:22:40 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1846619: defining beans [dao,metier,dataSource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
WARN : org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1846619: defining beans [dao,metier,dataSource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at toto.tata.titi.test.test.main(test.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:50)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 26 more
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

 
 <bean id="dao" class="toto.tata.titi.dao.BanqueDaoImpl" />
 <bean id="metier" class="toto.tata.titi.metier.BanqueMetierImpl">
  <!-- injection de dependance -->
  <!-- on associe objet dao a objet metier -->
  <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
 </bean>

 
 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banque5" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
   <list>
    <value>persistence.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MY_P_U"></property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
 </bean>
 
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
 <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/
ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="MY_P_U" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <properties>
          
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You have a 'NoSuchMethodError' : You have probably deployed incompatibles libraries

Comment: Try to add `@Repository`above BanqueDaoImpl class declaration

Comment: Can you list all the hibernate libraries/versions you are using in this project. (if you have a pom.xml please show that).

Answer (score 0):

in your pom.xml change the version of hibernate-jpa 2.0 to 2.1

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please, clean up all errors and nested exceptions. I had many similar errors. I commented out these beans in my application context and it seems that it is working well for now.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'licenseBean': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [] for bean with name '' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-tree.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```